# requestLocationUpdates generates locations after..?

Tags: java, android

I got an error on my application so I need to check every single line to find the error which leads me to this question:

In case that I send a 10 seconds as minTime in the requestLocationUpdates method, the method will start to count to 10 exactly when it call the listener? or when the listener method is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually neither. Behind the scenes, a background service handles getting updates from the hardware and passing them up to an eventual listener. Because of the multithreading, the minTime parameter simply means how many seconds must pass between "hardware" update messages before a message is ultimately passed on to your listener.

Relying on this internal 10 second interval would not be recommended. It is simply used as a flow control to make sure you don't get updates more often than required.

Comment: Thank you! the 10 minute example is - an example :) I'm generating every 10 minutes a location.